# Object appears to be empty inside of react render() even if previous logging proves that it's not

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have this component in my React app:

```
class ChannelList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("1. return: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.channels));
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.channels.map(chan => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(chan));
                    return (
                        <Channel
                            key={chan.id}
                            channel={chan}
                            {...this.props} // Pass all properties
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

The first log method reads like this: `1. return: [{"channel":{"id":1,"name":"asdf"}}]`
The second log method like this: `{"channel":{"id":1,"name":"asdf"}}`

But when running this code I get an error message, that each child should have a unique "key".
The problem appears to be that when I use `chan.id` the object is empty.
Since I logged it just three lines before proving it is not there must be some other issue with this. I am new to JavaScript in general and React in particular.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or the way I'm trying to access th `id` value?

Comment: Yes, you're not actually paying attention to the object you've logged :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chan.channel.id

```
class ChannelList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("1. return: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.channels));
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.channels.map(chan => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(chan));
                    return (
                        <Channel
                            key={chan.channel.id}
                            channel={chan}
                            {...this.props} // Pass all properties
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Banged my head on this for an hour without seeing the obvious. Thanks!